# postgres sql file dump showing different characters

Tags: postgresql

I got a sql dump from my co-worker working on ubuntu and the sql seems to be like the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Now if I try to restore from this file, it does not work on my windows 7.

Later I tried to create a new db in windows, did a sqldump, imported in another test db and all works fine.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to clean this sql file ?
2. Is the file corrupted ?
3. Should I request another clean sql file ?

Let me know if anyone can help me out.

Comment: That's not a SQL dump, that's a dump in custom format. You need to use `pg_restore` to restore it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - when I did `pg_restore -d test file.sql` I got the following error `pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 3, expected 5)`

Comment: Then the dump file is indeed corrupted or maybe it was created with a different pg_dump version

Comment: Actually I got a new sql file from my co-worker and did pg_restore and it worked for me.`pg_restore -h hostname -d dbname -U username filename.sql`. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Got a new sql file from my co-worker and did pg_restore and it worked for me.
`pg_restore -h hostname -d dbname -U username filename.sql`. This time I received a readable sql file.